# Android LinearLayout not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with my xml. I have a LinearLayout which contains a chart (aChartEngine library) and if i set the height to 480dp it shows the chart, if i set the height to wrap_content, nothing shows. I think there is a problem with the parent or something. Here is the entire xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".Sniffer" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                   <!-- removed some content here, 2 much space and not relevant -->

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                      android:layout_width="1dp"
                      android:layout_height="30dp">
                    </View>

                    <View
                        style="@style/Divider"
                        android:background="@color/semi_transparent"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                      android:layout_width="1dp"
                      android:layout_height="30dp">
                    </View>

                    <View
                        style="@style/Divider"
                        android:background="@color/semi_transparent"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                      android:layout_width="1dp"
                      android:layout_height="30dp">
                    </View>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/chart"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="500dp"                    
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</TabHost>
```

Under tab4 there is a LinearLayout with chart id. That is where i place my chart. I tried using weight attribute and 0dip but still not working, only with a fixed height.

LE: The LinearLayout is empty because I add contents to it programatically.

Code snippet for chart.

```
public void createGraphCPU(List<BasicNameValuePair> values){

    mSeries = new CategorySeries("");
    mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    statisticsTab.removeAllViews();

    Collections.shuffle(COLORS_LIST);
    for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++){
        double value=Double.parseDouble(values.get(i).getValue());
        mSeries.add( values.get(i).getName(),value );
        SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(COLORS_LIST.get(i%COLORS_LIST.size()));
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    }

     mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20); 
     mRenderer.setChartTitle("CPU Energy Consumption");
     mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);  
     mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);  
     mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 15, 15, 0 });  
     mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);  

     if (mChartView != null) {
          mChartView.repaint();
    }
     else{
         mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries,mRenderer);
        statisticsTab.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
     }

}
```

Comment: The LinearLayout whose id is chart, looks like empty, because there aren't any items in it?

Comment: Yea sorry about not specifying , i add items in it programatically. Its only a GraphicView from aChartEngine library, but it's there

Comment: Then, the problem is probably with the layout params you assign to the chart view. Can you share the code where you add the chart view?

Comment: are you using LinearLayout.LayoutParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you can see your chart when you specify a fixed height for `android:layout_height` and that you can't see your chart when you use `wrap_content`. If so the reason for this behavior is that your chart does not provide a height by itself -- indeed you specify `fill_parent` as its width and height. So if your LinearLayout wants to be as small as your chart (`wrap_content`) and your chart wants to be as large as its surrounding LinarLayout (`fill_parent`) Android will not display your chart at all.

Solution might then be to ask yourself better what width and height you want to give to your charts.

Comment: Currently i have three charts , each on a different linearLayout. Atm each linearlayout has a height and the chart right behind it is clipped by the previous linearLayout. Let me try to set a fixed height for the chart itself and see if the clipping is gone.

Comment: Can't find a way to specify the height for the chart itself, i have to use the LinearLayout's height that contains it, i think there is no other choice. If someone used aChartEngine and knows how to, please offer some insight.That being said, how do i make 3 linearlayouts with a height of 400dp lets say one below the other and not clip.E.g my second chart is clipped to half. I tried wrapping them into a RelativeLayout and use layout_below and still the chart is clipped.

Comment: If you want to see your views within a scrollable view you need to use a ``ListView``. ``LinearLayout`` is not the right solution for your problem. When you use a ListView then apply for every list item a view height of ``400dp``.

Comment: Here is a SS of how it looks: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/309x464q90/845/4xgu.png and  https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/309x464q90/585/re2c.png

Comment: Your problem is that you are using LinearLayout within a ScrollView. This is wrong. Use ListView only. No LinearLayout. I cannot give you more as this help on this.

Comment: You mean ListView instead of ScrollView , not LinearLayout. A bit late to change my entire format. I eventually added only one chart at a time and toggle between them with a button on the options menu. I'm gonna live the question here if someone has a answer to the original question. Ty Lars